# How to set defaults when creating a record from a visualforce page button/link?

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I can create a link or button in a visualforce page that references an object's links or buttons with a line like this:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.SiteProgram__c.New_Holidaybtn)}" ...
```

but when I do this, any default values that I've set via constructs like this "{!SiteProgram__c.Name}" in the original button or link show up blank.  Here's the code for the button.  I've checked the ID ("00N00000008igMg") and it is correct for the field in the new object.

```
/a0e/e?CF00N00000008igMg={!SiteProgram__c.Name}&CF00N00000008igMg_lkid={!SiteProgram__c.Id}&retURL={!SiteProgram__c.Id}
```

The Visualforce page uses the object's standard controller.  The object is a custom object. What have I missed? Can this be done with a standard controller?  I realize it could be done with a controller extension, but I'm hoping to keep this simple(r).

Here's the full VF page code.

```
<apex:page standardController="SiteProgram__c"  docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:outputLabel value="Site: " for="SiteOF"/>
<apex:outputField label="Site" id="SiteOF" value="{!SiteProgram__c.Name}"/><br/>
<apex:outputLabel value="District: " for="DistrictOF"/>
<apex:outputField label="District" id="DistrictOF" value="{!SiteProgram__c.SchoolDistrictProgram__c}"/><br/> 
<apex:outputLabel value="Start Date: " for="StartDateOF"/>        
<apex:outputField id="StartDateOF" value="{!SiteProgram__c.Start_Date__c}"/><br/>   
<apex:outputLabel value="End Date: " for="EndDateOF"/>               
<apex:outputField id="EndDateOF" value="{!SiteProgram__c.End_date__c}"/> <br/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.SiteProgram__c.New_Holidaybtn)}" value="Create New Holiday" id="whatevs"></apex:commandButton>
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.SiteProgram__c.New_Holidaylnk)}" value="Create New Holiday" id="whatevs6"></apex:commandButton>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**edited to add**  I'm not going to add my own answer yet as I'd still like to know how to use URLFOR with $Action and passed inputs.

I tried many variations on the following including using commandlink instead of commandbutton:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.SiteProgram__c.New_Holiday,null,[CF00N00000008igMg=SiteProgram__c.Name,CF00N00000008igMg_lkid=SiteProgram__c.ID,saveURL=SiteProgram__c.ID])}" value="Create New Holiday" id="whatevs66"></apex:commandButton>
```

as there seems to be some disagreement out there about quotes and param names I also tried

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.SiteProgram__c.New_Holiday,null,['CF00N00000008igMg'=SiteProgram__c.Name,'CF00N00000008igMg_lkid'=SiteProgram__c.ID,'saveURL'=SiteProgram__c.ID])}" value="Create New Holiday" id="whatevs66"></apex:commandButton>
```

In all cases, the resulting URL had the parameter names but blank values.  I suspect the parameter names came from the underlying action, but I haven't tested that out yet.

**Solution** - replaces a previous answer based on straight URL hacking

The key point here is that the values between the square brackets "[]" (URLFOR parameter 3) have their own syntax.  The URLFOR call is within the bounds of the the curly brackets "{}", so I suspect the rule switch is necessary to avoid confusion.  Text needs to quoted (eg, 'CF00N00000008igMg_lkid') and variables don't need any special decoration.  The equals sign does not need quotes.  Concatenating values requires a "&".

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Holiday__c.New,null,['CF00N00000008igMg'=SiteProgram__c.Name,'CF00N00000008igMg_lkid'=SiteProgram__c.ID,'saveURL'='apex/SimpleSiteProgram?id='&SiteProgram__c.ID])}" value="Create New Holiday" id="holidaybtn"></apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: The second command button looks good but instead of using your custom button can you try using the standard new action for holiday object.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Just finished testing it.  I'll add the correct button code later tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a nice [blog](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html) that explains the URLFOR Method:

> {!URLFOR(target, id, [inputs], [no override])}
>
> Parameters shown in brackets ([]) are optional.
>
> **target**: You can replace target with a URL or action, s-control or
>   static resource.
>   **id**: This is id of the object or resource name (string
>   type) in support of the provided target.
>   **inputs**: Any additional URL
>   parameters you need to pass you can use this parameter. you will to
>   put the URL parameters in brackets and separate them with commas ex:
>   [param1="value1", param2="value2"]
>   **no override**: A Boolean value which
>   defaults to false, it applies to targets for standard Salesforce
>   pages. Replace "no override" with "true" when you want to display a
>   standard Salesforce page regardless of whether you have defined an
>   override for it elsewhere.

Basically, you just call the existing new holiday button and set the parameters in the URLFOR like this...

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Holiday__c.New,null
,['CF00N00000008igMg'=SiteProgram__c.Name,'CF00N00000008igMg_lkid'=SiteProgram__c.Id, 'retURL'=SiteProgram__c.Id])}" value="Create New Holiday" id="theButton"/>
```

Comment: This sure looks like it should work, but I've tried this a number of ways without success.  I'm going to edit my answer to show a solution - even though it doesn't pass any inputs to the action.

Comment: Can you paste what you have, I was able to get it to work on my dev org